# Share link URLs are not linking directly to answers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, sharing

Each answer has a "share" link under it, so that a user might give a URL to someone as a means of directing them directly to that answer within the page. **URL Example:**

https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/140978

However, the URL produced by this feature does NOT link to the answer itself. It instead links to the question as a whole.

**Update:** It seems to work if I'm logged in, but for users who are not logged in, it just links to the question instead of the answer anchor.

To reproduce this behavior, open the link above in a private browser tab (without logging in).

**Update 2:** Now it seems to be working no matter what. Believe me, this was not working a few minutes ago!